# Formatting $wpdb->get_results

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I used 
...

```php
$result = $wpdb->get_results( $query );
foreach ( $result as $print ) {
    echo $print->name;
    echo $print->count;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

output is:

```php
jo2 
clea10
jim10
```

Now I somehow need to make it like

```php
  ['jo', '2'],
  ['clea', '10'],
  ['jim', '10'],
```

I tried

```php
<?php
     foreach ( $result as $print ) {
         echo "['".$print->name."', '".$print->count."'],";
     }
 ?>
```

And

```php
if($result->num_rows > 0){
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
          echo "['".$row['name']."', ".$row['count']."],";
      }
}
```

But it does not work. I'm trying to run this inside Wordpress using wordpressDatabase that is why I used `$wpdb->get_results`

Comment: Try `print_r($result)` and see if you are getting any data back

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you were querying so I mocked up another example to just return the pages of the site. You can substitute post_name for name and count for ID in your example.

I just added spaces to your attempt to match WP Standards a little closer but working with quotations is never that readable.

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "
                SELECT *
                FROM  $wpdb->posts
                    WHERE post_type = 'page'
            " );

foreach ( $result as $key => $print ) {
  echo "['" . $print->post_name . "', '" . $print->ID . "'],<br>";
}
```

Another approach, if you are comfortable reading it this way, is to use double quotes around the entire output.

```
foreach ( $result as $key => $print ) {
  echo "['{$print->post_name}', '{$print->ID}'],<br>";
}
```

If neither approach is working I'd suggest you may have an issue with your query in general but it is hard to say without more inforamtion